# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) intermittently

Tags: ssl, encryption, ssl-certificate, ios9, tls1.2

I am using an iOS app and I get the below error when testing in iOS 9.

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)    
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
```

I found a number of links saying this could be due to the NSAppTransportSecurity suggesting to add exception for my domain or to disable ATS. But my server does support TLS1.2 and I get this issue only intermittently. Had this been due to the NSTransportSecurity I assume that the issue should be consistent.
Whats strange is that this is not consistent. The app works fine and is able to connect to server in most cases. But after a while I get the above error. I use NSURLCONNECTION. Most of the app interaction is like click on a button and it makes a network call to server(tomcat). Once the SSL failed error occurs, the only way to get the app to send requests successfully to server is by killing the app and starting again. I have tried changing the connection from wifi to 3g during the issue, and even restarting the server once the issue happens but I could find no luck. I am able to work fine with safari and other apps.  I have been trying to find a solution for this for some time now. The server is not forward secrecy enabled.

To check the issue deeply I verified the SSL packets from the client.
When the issue occurs the client is sending a different list of ciphers compared to when the connection is working good.
[image: Cipher list during issue]

When the connection is working good I could see the below list of ciphers being sent.

[image]

It was also seen that during the issue the client hello packet was shown as SSL where as when the connection is good the client hello packet is shown as TLS1.2

During issue
[image]

When there is no issue
[image]

I am using the same NSurlconnetion class to connect to server throughout the app. I am confused why and how there could be such a discrepancy and how the same server call that works once is not working later. Does the above data suggest that during the issue the client is trying to connect via tls1.0 or lower? The server supports TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 only. The issue is found only in iOS 9. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The app will probably start with TLS 1.2 and a will offer ciphers which are new with TLS 1.2 too (the ones with GCM in the name). Then I guess there is some handshake problem, maybe cause by temporary server problems, some middlebox (firewall) in between or  something else. From then on the app assumes that there are problems with TLS 1.2 and will attempt to use a downgraded connection, i.e TLS 1.0. and stay this way because "it knows" that TLS 1.2 will not work.

This kind of downgrades is often seen in browsers too but usually they remember to do the downgrade only if it was at least once successful. Could there be some SSL intercepting middlebox (firewall) involved which causes the original TLS 1.2 to fail and the downgrade to succeed? I.E. does the problem happens only after the device connected once through this middlebox and then later tries to reconnect to your site?

Comment: is it possible to have a iOS client to connect to a web server with TLS 1.2 only without ATS turned on? Is the ATS the only way to talk to a TLS 1.2 web server?

Comment: @Aviva: comments are not intended for asking new questions. Please ask a new question instead with full details about the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry, Stackoverflow limits the number of newbies questions I can ask.

Comment: @Aviva: from my understanding ATS only restricts the connection to only use secure settings. But that does not mean that secure settings like TLS 1.2 can only be used together with ATS. But I have no experience with iOS in particular but only with TLS stacks in general. For more details please ask a new question.